# trying to save the newWeather object to MongoDb, but without success. ReferenceError: location is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

trying to save the newWeather object to MongoDb, but without success,
in console.log I have this err:

```
(node:21296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

```
router.post("/weather", (req, res) => {
  let search = req.body.search;
  const urls = [
    `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=1&per_page=6&orientation=portrait&query=Berlin&client_id=${clientID}`,
    `https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?app_id=${appId}&app_code=${appCode}&product=observation&name=Berlin`
  ];

  //=====================================
  Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))).then(
    ([api_1, api_2]) => {
      const displayImages = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < api_1.results.length; i++) {
        displayImages.push(api_1.results[i].urls.small);
      }

      const displayWeather = {
        temperature: Math.round(
          api_2.observations.location[0].observation[0].temperature
        ),
        city: api_2.observations.location[0].city,
        description: api_2.observations.location[0].observation[0].description,
        iconLink: api_2.observations.location[0].observation[0].iconLink
      };

      const { temperature, city, description, iconLink } = displayWeather;

      const newWeather = {
        displayImages,
        temperature,
        city,
        description,
        iconLink,
        search: req.body.search,
        location
      };

      WeatherPost.create(newWeather)
        .then(newCreatedWeather => {
          res.json(newCreatedWeather);
          console.log(newCreatedWeather);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(404).json({ notfound: "No post found(weather)" });
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      const newWeather = {
        displayImages,
        temperature,
        city,
        description,
        iconLink,
        search: req.body.search,
        location // where is this declared?
      };
```

In your URLs you hard-code the city name, so I guess this `location` variable is indeed `not defined`.

Comment: I got rid of the location from the object and I used hardcode city. I tested it in postman and it works, but when I use variable search I have the same err

Comment: What do you mean _when I use variable search_? Maybe update your code with your latest changes so that I can see what it's about?

Comment: let search = req.body.search; const urls = [ `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=1&per_page=6&orientation=portrait&query=${search} &client_id=${clientID}`, `https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?app_id=${appId}&app_code=${appCode}&product=observation&name=${search} ` ];

Comment: I'm not sure, but now you have an opportunity to enhance your debugging skills: try logging the variable along the way, and see where it doesn't have the proper value...

Comment: Yes you are right. I can write if statement and see if the value will appear in the console.log. Thanks very much for the hint